# Entity Framework - Read Lock on Record

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity, entity-relationship

I'm calling same database from **different applications** using Entity Framework. However, when one application is reading/updating a record, I do not want other applications to read that data.

I tried with the following sample code; however, they are still able to read the record.

Any suggestion OR different approaches will be highly appreciated!

```
using (Entities context = new Entities(ConnectionString))
{
    DBTable entity;

    do
    {
        entity = context.DBTable
            .Where(item => item.IsLock == false)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (entity != null)
        {
            // Map entity to class
            ......


            // Lock the record; it will be unlocked later by a calling method.
            entity.IsLock = true;
            context.SaveChanges();

            count++;
        }

    } while (entity != null && count < 100);
}
```

Edited: Basically, I read a record and do something (it sometimes take long). Then update the record with success/fail flag (if fail other can do that again). I do not want other applications do the **successful** task multiple times.

Comment: If you want to lock records while editing, consider dBase. Better check if your aproach is really necessary, it is not the normal practice.

Comment: If it's not long running, you can use a TransactionScope.

Comment: This doesn't sound like the kind of thing you want to use database/transaction locks on - ""(it sometime takes long)"".  I would recommend you adding a column to the table in question - IsLocked, and updating that as required.  It's likely a more complicated will be required though (what if a process locks a record and then the process is somehow terminated).  To counter this, consider a second table that keeps track of your locks (Lock Id, Process Id, Expiry) and then adding the Lock Id to whichever record you want to remain untouched?

Comment: @Smudge202 - I added IsLock column. I think the problem is, when threads from different applications read the same record (almost) exact same time, lock doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  If you don't mind fixing this with SQL, create a stored procedure.  In the stored procedure do a SELECT on the record WITH UPDLOCK ([see here for information on table hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)).  After the SELECT, update the record to IsLock.  This prevents any other process from reading the data whilst you are checking/setting the IsLock field.  Hope that helps

Comment: @Smudge202 - Thank you! I'll definitely use store procedure as you suggested, if I don't find any solution with Entity Famework.

Comment: @Smudge: put your comment as an answer so it can be accepted and question is not unanswered.

Comment: @Ladislav for some reason I didn't get the notification to winmyans response.  Thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Moved from comment to an answer:*

If you don't mind fixing this with SQL, create a stored procedure. In the stored procedure do a SELECT on the record WITH UPDLOCK ([see here for information on table hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)). After the SELECT, update the record to IsLock. This prevents any other process from reading the data whilst you are checking/setting the IsLock field.

Hope that helps